# Get Product List with more details in Magento2 API

Tags: magento2

I am working on a native application and need to get the a list of products based on category.

Like when a user clicks on a category I have to show a list of products inside that category.

I tried an API but it's only giving three fields in return:

```
http://localhost/magento/index.php/rest/V1/categories/21/products
```

Response

```
[
    {
        "sku": "WH01",
        "position": 10001,
        "category_id": "21"
    },
    {
        "sku": "WH02",
        "position": 10001,
        "category_id": "21"
    },
    {
        "sku": "WH03",
        "position": 10001,
        "category_id": "21"
    },
    {
        "sku": "WH04",
        "position": 10001,
        "category_id": "21"
    }
]
```

I need more information like name, image, price and more.

Comment: Try this http://localhost/magento/swagger#/catalogProductRenderListV1

Answer (score 0):

You can use magento's default product list API with searchCriteria.

http://localhost/magento/index.php/rest/all/V1/products?searchCriteria[filterGroups][0][filters][0][field]=**category_id**&searchCriteria[filterGroups][0][filters][0][value]=**21**&searchCriteria[filterGroups][0][filters][0][conditionType]=**in**

http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.2/rest/performing-searches.html